# How to get all possible filter options for a particular model across relationships?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, many-to-many, django-queryset

I'm trying to expose a very flexible query interface for powerusers of my django application and I need to find every way to filter a given model in respect to the model hierarchy it is embedded in.

I have a deeply nested set of models like this:

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Team(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(City)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Employee(models.Model):
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
    location = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Task(models.Model):
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
```

With [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/) I can construct a complex query, for example finding all tasks that are assigned to employees from Munich:

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(assignee__location="Munich")
```

or something more complex, going through M2M:

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(assignee__teams__location__="Munich")
```

I want to guide my users through the process of constructing a meaningful complex query and would like to display all choices they have to filter the model `Task` by, so I came up with this algorithm:

```
def traverse(waiting,result=list(),grave=set()):
    if not waiting:
        # If there is nothing waiting we are done
        return
    objekt, prefix = waiting.pop(0) # Remove an item from the front of the queue
    SEPARATION_CHARACTER = "__" #django uses __ instead of . in query strings
    newprefix=prefix
    if prefix:
        newprefix = prefix +SEPARATION_CHARACTER
    try:
        modelname = objekt._meta.object_name
        if modelname in grave:
            # If the current model name is in the graveyard, it has been touched by another
            # chain and doesn't need to be processed.
            return

        # We now know we are dealing with a complex object that may have fields
        grave.add(objekt._meta.object_name)
        fields = objekt._meta.get_all_field_names()
        for field in fields:
            # For every attribute of the field, create a new tuple in waiting
            try:
                waiting.append((getattr(objekt,field),newprefix+field))
            except:
                pass

        for field in fields:
            traverse(waiting, result, grave)
    except:
        # If objekt._meta doesn't exist, the thing is not a complex object and we can stop this chain.
        # add the fully qualified path to the result
        result.append(prefix)
    return result
```

This will successfully find all filter possibilities for a given model by following `ForeignKey`s, but will stop on reverse `ForeignKey`s and `ManyToManyField`s.

How can I extend my algorithm to give me all possible filter options?

Comment: Did you ever find a way?

Comment: No. I finished that internship and I don't know what happened :)